# ExtJs 4.1 TreeGrid treecolumn custom renderer

Tags: extjs4.1

Is it possible to merge 2 columns in TreeGrid, when one of them is xtype 'treecolumn'?

For now I have 2 separate columns, one is standard treecolumn, second is templatecolumn with custom template (basically an image)

[image: now it looks like this]

What I would like to get should look like this:

[image: what I'm trying to do]

So that second column content is added to first but aligned to right.

I have no idea how to even start with that kind of renderer :(

This is code for my columns so far:

```
{
    xtype : 'treecolumn',
    text : 'Dział/Pracownik',
    width : 200,
    sortable : true,
    hideable: false,
    dataIndex : 'Name',
    renderer: function (v, m, r) {
        if(r.get('leaf')==true)
            m.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="<img src=services/Images.ashx?login='+r.get('login')+' width=60px height=60px>"';
            return v;
    }
},
{
    text : 'Zdj', 
    width: 40, 
    align : 'center', 
    dataIndex : 'Name', 
    sortable : false, 
    resizable: false,
    xtype : 'templatecolumn', 
    tpl : imgTpl
},
...
var imgTpl = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<tpl if="values.leaf == true">',
        '<img src="services/Images.ashx?login={login}" width="25px" height="25px"/>',
    '</tpl>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

I will really be gratefully for any hints on how to merge those 2 columns.

Comment: trying to get something similar to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is instead using template I've used renderer, so my column now looks like this:

```
{
    xtype : 'treecolumn',
    text : 'Employee',
    width : 200,
    sortable : true,
    hideable : false,
    dataIndex : 'Name',
    renderer : function(v, m, r) {
        if (r.get('leaf')) {
            return '<div style="float: left">'
            + r.get('Name')
            + '</div><img data-qtip="<img src=services/Images.ashx?login='
            + r.get('login')
            + ' width=60px height=60px/>" src="services/Images.ashx?login='
            + r.get('login')
            + '" width="25px" height="25px" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px"/>';
        }

    return '<div style="float: left">' + r.get('Name') + '</div>';
    }
}
```

If element is leaf then I display extra image in the right of my column + I've added bigger image after rollover.

To have this working I had to change some css inside ext-all.css:

> .x-grid-with-row-lines .x-tree-icon{margin-top:1px; float: left}
>   .x-grid-with-row-lines .x-tree-elbow,.x-grid-with-row-lines .x-tree-elbow-end,.x-grid-with-row-lines .x-tree-elbow-plus,.x-grid-with-row-lines .x-tree-elbow-end-plus,.x-grid-with-row-lines .x-tree-elbow-empty,.x-grid-with-row-lines .x-tree-elbow-line{height:19px;background-position:0 -1px; float: left}

I had to add float:left to all images that are displayed in that cell:

- x-tree-elbow
- x-tree-elbow-end
- x-tree-elbow-plus
- x-tree-icon

I know that this can be optimised a lot, but for me it works fine. If some ExtJS guru could tweak it to work better then you're welcome :)

Comment: I am afraid to touch your css but here are some pointers for optimization of the renderer:  1 - you do not need to access record to get the Name attribute as it is already provided for you in the 'v' variable. (You have two of those calls).  2 -  I would consider using an XTemplate or a String.format() to create your html string - it would probably be more efficient than doing string concatenation (and more readable). 3 - consider moving the url of image loader into a config variable so that you could replace it later if needed.

Comment: Thanks for comments :) I'm just starting ExtJS, so all optimisation ideas are welcome. What would me best idea to implement app config? To store all important urls in one place? For user preferences I have a store that holds current user settings and 2 functions to get setting (if there isn't specific setting function returns default value) and second to update settings. I assume that I don't need so complex way of storing application settings as they are changed ones a while. What would be the best way? Could You create a basic example for a beginner like me? :)

Comment: You can use your imagination of how to implement it of course. Here is one way I found helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/Zk4Ah/1/ In this example My.app definition has a 'con' object that stores a named url 'url1'. To get it I use My.app.con.url1 (see onMainReady function). The idea here is not to put it into a Global variable, but use My name space.

Comment: Thanks for that great sample :) I'm building my application Object Oriented, because I always was thinking that MVC was to hard, but seeing Your code realised me that it isn't so hard :) I'll try to rebuild my application in MVC. Thanks ones more!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing with that:

```
 renderer:function (value, meta, record) {
                    var tasks = record.get("tasks"),
                        tpl =     this.taskImgTpl,
                        type, qtip;
                    if (tasks && tasks.length >0){
                        Ext.each(tasks, function(task){
                            if(task.refType) {
                                type = task.refType;
                            } else {
                                type = task.type.name;
                            }
                            qtip = Ext.String.format('Status:  {0}  Assignee:  {1}  %Complete:  {2}',task.state,task.assignee||'',task.pctComplete);
                            value += tpl.apply([type, qtip]);
                        },this);
                    }

                    return value;
                }
```

And the image template that is being inserted is :

```
taskImgTpl:new Ext.XTemplate(" &nbsp; &nbsp;  <img class='{0} h16' width='16px' data-qtitle='{0}' data-qwidth='120' data-qtip='{1}'/>")
```

where h16 is a class that gives height:16px, and the dynamically inserted class carries a background image (16x16) of whatever the type of object is being displayed. You of course can just set the src attribute instead.

Comment: I've added my answer, maybe You'll find it useful or You'll be able to improve it.

Comment: yep that's the idea, see my comments for some optimization.